# $L_1 =(a^nb^n)$ and $L_2 =(a^nb^{2n})$. Is $L_1 \cup L_2$ DCFL?

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

I think that since $a^nb^n$ is not regular (applied pumping lemma), so is $L_2$.

Therefore, $L_1 \cup L_2$ is not cfL.

Is that correct?

Comment: Being CFL is entirely different from being a DCFL and both are entirely different from being regular.  Which do you actually want?

Comment: Is it DCFL or not/am i understanding correctly being DCFL means it can be accepted by a deterministic PDA

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$L_1$ is produced by

S := $\epsilon$
  |  aSb

$L_2$ is produced by

S := $\epsilon$
  | aSbb

(assuming $a^a$ is a typo, meaning $a^n$)

Comment: yes  $a^n$ but is it dCFL

Comment: Both $L_1$ and $L_2$ are DCFL. Their union isn't because it cannot be deterministically decided to process single b's or pairs of b's after a sequence of a's.